# How to remove email address from people card

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-365-developer

In the below image of the profile card, you can see the 2 email addresses. I have some questions regarding this.

1. how we can remove this 2nd email address?
2. how can we check the origin of 2nd email address?

[image]